# is it possible to do multinomial logit regression where multiple outcomes can occur at once?

Tags: regression, logistic, multinomial-logit

**Example situation (everything is made up):**

I have data on fast food orders by customer at a restaurant.

The outcome options are:

- burger
- soda
- fry

They can be purchased solo or in any combination.

The explanatory variables are:

- Cash on hand in dollars
- Dummy variable for if the customer has a coupon or not
- Time since last meal in hours

I want to find the odds of any item being ordered as well as any combination of items being ordered like burger and soda or fry and soda.

Should I code the outcomes like this:

- 0 = burger
- 1 = soda
- 2 = fry
- 3 = burger, soda
- 4 = burger, fry
- 5 = burger, soda, fry
- 6 = soda, fry

Will this scale if more options are added?

The other thought I had would be to add more rows with the same explanatory data, but with another outcome as needed. For example ID 14:

**| ID | Cash | Coupon | Time  | Outcome |**

| 6  | $12 | No     | 3hrs  | Burger  |

| 14 | $45  | yes    | 36hrs | Fry     |

| 14 | $45  | Yes    | 36hrs | Soda    |

I am not sure what this method will do in terms of altering the assumptions of the model.

Any help would be appreciated. As well as any other observations you might have.

Regards,

Comment: @mdewey, your answer helped me as I have a similar data structure to Michael. But I am still not sure how to fit the model as I cannot find the code for this. Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 2):

You first option will work but it has at least two disadvantages. First as you suggests the number of outcome goes up as $2^k$ for $k$ types of fast food (b) it treats each outcome as defined separately whereas you know that the combination ones are combinations of single types. The second option would require you to take account of the fact that an ID may account for more than one row. I think you might need a random intercept for ID. If I were setting out the dataset I would have three (in your example) rows for each ID and I would have an additional column 0/1 for whether they bought that or not. Then fit a logistic model with a random effect.

These are just suggestions and your underlying scientific question may help you decide or possibly there might be other answers with other suggestion.